# how to package kivy and python to executable file?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, exe

I have two files in a folder:

1. ‘main.py`
2. `calculator.kv`

I tried packaging in command prompt with

```
pyinstaller main.py
```

I am not getting any errors during the process, but when i try to open the EXE file I am not getting the desired window.

Comment: You may want to read [ask].

Comment: Have a look at the `Pyinstaller` [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search). You probably need to use a `--add-data` option to include your `kv` file in the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have followed these steps from [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html).You didn't mention your exact `spec` file and the error you get. But i guess you are missing this important part in `spec` file :

```
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew
coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('examples-path\\demo\\touchtracer\\'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='touchtracer')
```

Comment: I tried the above steps and still I m getting the error message when I try to open the exe file . It's telling failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgred